How does Flutter's repaintBoundary.toImage() impact the quality of the saved image?
I am building a graphic design app in Flutter. In my app, the user have an image with a shadow and border, which means that I can not save the image to their gallery directly because I would lose the shadow and border. Here is some example code for more context:
child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: _project.selectedEntity == widget ? Border.all(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
              ) : null,
            ),
            child: SimpleShadow(
                opacity: _shadow == null ? 0 : _shadow!.color.opacity,
                sigma: _shadow == null ? 0 : _shadow!.blurRadius,
                color: _shadow == null ? Colors.transparent : _shadow!.color,
                offset: Offset.zero,
                child: Image.memory(
                  _imageBytes,
                  width: _imageBounds.width,
                  height: _imageBounds.height,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  gaplessPlayback: true,
                )
              ),
          )

Basically I need to save the entire widget as an image, so I was thinking about wrapping it with a RepaintBoundary and taking advantage of the toImage() funciton.
My question is, is that the same idea as taking a screenshot, meaning that the image quality will be limited by the pixel density of the user's screen? If so, can I use the pixelRatio parameter to get around that, or will this only magnify the lesser quality of the saved image?
Thanks for any help or resources you can provide!
I have tried increasing the pixelRatio, like so:
ui.Image projectImage = await projectBoundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 10);

However, since I am testing this app on a cheap, low-res android, I can not tell if it helps or not: both images appear exactly the same since they are both higher quality than what my phone can display.
My main concern with this method is that it does not actually improve the quality, rather it just magnifies the same pixel data that a screenshot would have.
If anyone has any ideas about how I can do some testing I would appreciate that too. Thanks!
